# How To Draw Function Graph On Windowphone

Tags: c#, math, windows-phone-8

I want to draw a function graph, i.e.  `y = 2x + 1`. I have tried to search on Google, but I don't know where to start.
Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You want to NuGet/Download a free charting library or you can create one yourself.  But since you're asking such a basic question, I think you should give AM Chart or Sparrow Chart a try.  Just try doing a search for them using the built in NuGet inside Visual Studios.

Once you have included the necessary libraries, all you have to do is compute a list of sample points from the equation that you want the chart to draw.

Simple Example:

```
List<Point> point_list = new List<Point>();

float starting_x_value = 0;
float ending_x_value = 10;
float step = 0.5f;

for (float current_x = starting_x_value; current_x <= ending_x_value; current_x = current_x + step)
{
    float calculated_y = 2 * (current_x) + 1;     // your equation
    Point p = new Point(current_x, calculated_y); // create the point
    point_list.Add(p);                            // add it to the point list
}
```

Then all you have to do is set the List of Points as the collection of whatever chart's collection source.